# Expected value probability question

Tags: probability

> > The question is : Rewa and Stefan have been playing a game of chance. The game involves several rounds. The
> >     winner of each round gains one point. The overall winner of the game is the first person to gain a
> >     total of three points.
> >
> > The probability that Rewa wins any particular round is $k$.
> >     Suppose that in the course of a game, Rewa has two points and Stefan has one point.
> >     Let the random variable $X$ be the number of rounds it takes for the game to be completed (ie the
> >     number of rounds before either Rewa or Stefan reaches three points, given that Rewa already has
> >     two points and Stefan has one point).
> >     Show that $Var(X )$ $= k (1 – k)$

I am extremely confused about the wording for this question , the only thing I have gotten so far is that if Rewa wins the probability is $k$ so the probability of Stephan winning is $1-k$

I also know the formula for $Var(x)$ $= E(x^2)-[E(x)]^2$

Comment: Hint: X equals 1 or 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

You will want to construct a probability distribution table for $X$. Notice that Rewa has **two** points, while Stefan has **one**. The game ends once a player wins three points. So you must consider the possible values of $X$. What are they? Can $X$ be zero? No, they **must** play at least one round to complete the game.

Can $X=1$? Yes, if Stefan  wins, then he gets a total of **three** points and the game ends. Is it possible for $X$ to be 2 or 3 or greater?

Once you have the distribution of $X$, then you can calculate the expectation in whichever manner you like.